# how to get an element before its added to the DOM?

Tags: jquery

How can you get an element before its added to the DOM (before append())

```
$('#enclosure_balance'+id).css({background:'red'})
```

Comment: Depends on where your element is, and if it exists yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way is by reference if you control or have access to the construction of it.

```
var s = $('<div id="stupid"/>')
```

Reference the variable / property which contains it. Since it hasn't been appended it's not accessible via the DOM methods.

If you want the element to be visibly hidden just append it to a container element that has offsetting css values ( eg position absolute, top -999em, left -999em )

EDIT: There are also document fragments: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/#postcomment but since they're not in the document itself, you can't reference the elements inside with `document.getElementById` and such.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the element is in a jQuery object.

Do either

```
obj.filter( selector )
```

or

```
obj.find( selector )
```

where `obj` is the jQuery object which contains your element, and `selector` is the selector which is supposed to match your element.

`filter` works if your element is one of the elements of the jQuery object.
`find` works when your jQuery object contains one or more elements which in turn have ancestors, and your element is among those ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question.  You already have a reference to the element, else you couldn't call append.  If you have this:

```
$("#parent").append("<div />");
```

Modify it to this:

```
var child = $("<div />");
child.css({ background: "red" });
$("#parent").append(child);
```